# Idea to do “fake” wifi between local VMBox

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, virtualbox, virtualization

I am the developper of [Live Raizo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/live-raizo/), an Linux environment to experiment the system on simulated and real networks.

LiveRaizo uses mainly VirtualBox with GNS3 as puppeteer

I want to add Wifi connections between VirtualBox VMs and I want that we can use in each VM the true system of wifi configuration of the Virtual OS (Linux, Microsoft, ...).

I know that VirtualBox does not emulate Wifi.

My soluce begins with 2 ideas :

- The VM in VirtualBox can capture USB device on the host and use it.
  For example, we can use in the guest a true Wifi USB dongle connected
  to the host.
- The linux kernel gives mac80211_hwsim. It is a Linux kernel module
  that can be used to simulate arbitrary number of IEEE 802.11 radios for mac80211. We can found an export called "mac80211_hwsim" on the github of [wolfhechel](https://github.com/wolfhechel/mac80211_hwsim). But i don't know if it is the last release of the kernel.

My questions are :

- Is it easy to modify "mac80211_hwsim" to create USB devices ? Then
  each VM will can capture one of this device and use it.
- If the USB device is captured by the VM, will this devices can always "communicate" together ?

But, if you have better idea, i want it :-)

Comment: Nobody has an answer, advice or idea ?

Comment: Or, do you know where i can find a template of code to create USB devices ? mainly wireless network devices, even if they do nothing. Perhaps i will could modify it to do the same as mac80211_hwsim.
I have already seek several times but with no success.